# su без ввода пароля

Tags: c++, linux, sudo, su

В системе есть user1, обладающий весьма обширными правами, и user2 c весьма урезанными.
User1 запускает откомпилированный бинарник, который должен выполнить одну команду от имени user2.
Я бы сделал это так:

```
system("su -c command user2");
```

если бы не последующий запрос на ввод пароля.
Так вот, как обойти данную проблему? Приветствуются любые решения.

Comment: Проблема с правами на файлы ? Если надо, чтобы результаты работы принадлежали user2, то можно применить chown. Вообще, @gecube в своем ответе правильно намекнул на wrapper, который делает setgid()/setuid(), наверное перед этим проверяет права на делегирование полномочий и т.п. Можно посмотреть на sudo (у нее много возможностей).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

/etc/sudoers

---

---

user1 ALL=/bin/su

---

---

И вообще рекомендую ознакомиться  с документацией по sudo
неправильный /etc/sudoers легкий способ получить все привелегии.

Answer (score 0):

setuid вроде как придуман именно для этого. Правда, реализация дырявая, но работает.

Comment: sudo?

Answer (score 0):

Я бы не рекомендовал так делать. Если вам что-то нужно сделать, но у текущего юзера не хватает прав на выполнение команды, то нужно соответсвующим образом настроить права группы, в которую входит пользователь. Или же дать права на выполнение конкретной операции данному пользователю. Надеюсь доступно изложил.

Comment: Наоборот ведь: у текущего юзера слишком много прав и он хочет выполнить потенциально опасное приложение, ограничив спектр его действий.

Comment: Знакомая ситуацию. В винде runas помогал и его клоны. Очень удобно, когда нужно запустить программу, которой не доверяешь, а виртуалку ставить слишком ресурсоемко. Проблема в том, что часть предлагаемых средств безусловно повышает привилегии. Т.е. получаемые привилегии = max (привилегии текущего юзера, привилегии с которыми запускаем прогу).